# Optical gap measured with a Tauc plot on a semi-metal

Tags: condensed-matter, spectroscopy

What optical gap would you expect to measure from a Tauc plot done with the absorption of a semi-metal ?

To be specific, I'm talking about a semimetal as in a "semi-conductor with an indirect negative band-gap", with a band structure that would look like this :

[image: semimetal band structure]

And I'm trying to contrast the measurement between this material and an almost identical material that is a semi-conductor with an indirect **positive** band-gap.

Comment: Never heard Tauc plot before. Had to look it up. Is that a common term?
I think this is a rather complicated issue. But it depends on phonon scattering amplitudes.
I don't understand why you compare this to a positive bandgap? Why change two parameters? The shift in k, and the shift in E?

Comment: @Leviathan If you're doing spectroscopy on (new) semi-conductors Tauc plots are fairly common yeah. In the comparison I'm trying to make, I'm only changing E (from -Eg to +Eg).

Comment: Ah, yes. I have read "direct positive band gap" at the end, for absolutely no good reason. My mistake.
Wouldn't there be just no optical gap? Phonon mediated transitions are always allowed here. It seems too simple an answer, so I'm confused whether I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Leviathan The Tauc plot doesn't "directly" probe the existence or the value of the optical gap, it's only an extrapolation of a value from the shape of the absorption above the band edge. And my question is : What number would the Tauc plot method give in the case of a semi-metal ? 
Or if you prefer my question could also be formulated as : What is the shape of the absorption α(E) of an idealized semi-metal ?